# Programmatically getting error messages/stack trace from Coded UI/unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, logging, visual-studio-2013

I'm writing a custom logger for a Coded UI project (though it would probably work for a unit test project as well). In the FinishTestLog() method of my Logger class, I am able to access the TestContext (using a reference provided elsewhere and stored in a private field) and get the CurrentTestOutcome, which is written to the log:

```
public static void FinishTestLog()
```

{
    ...

```
String message;
if (_testContext != null)
{
    message = String.Format("Ended execution of test case with outcome: {0}",
        _testContext.CurrentTestOutcome.ToString());
}
else
{
    message = "Ended execution of test case";
}

...
```

}

Sometimes tests fail, in which case the Test Explorer will show the error message and stack trace, which are written to the TRX file (if that is configured). It would be nice to be able to grab the error message and stack trace in the same manner as TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome, and not with wrapping every test method in a try/catch block. Is this info hidden somewhere in TestContext or another object?

Comment: Double click the failed test.

Comment: Test runners generally wrap the run context in a try/catch to get that message for you.

Comment: I should mention that this method is called from a method in the test class marked with the [TestCleanup] attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the late answer but this may help someone else. We get it by using Reflection on the TestContext object.  If someone knows how to do with with NUnit 2.x, please let me know.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns Error Stack Trace Details extracted from TestContext
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="testContext"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetErrorStackTraceFromTestContext(TestContext testContext)
    {
        const BindingFlags privateGetterFlags = System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField |
                                                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty |
                                                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy;

        var m_message = string.Empty; // Returns empty if TestOutcome is not failed
        if (testContext.CurrentTestOutcome == UnitTestOutcome.Failed)
        {
            // Get hold of TestContext.m_currentResult.m_errorInfo.m_stackTrace (contains the stack trace details from log)
            var field = testContext.GetType().GetField("m_currentResult", privateGetterFlags);
            var m_currentResult = field.GetValue(testContext);
            field = m_currentResult.GetType().GetField("m_errorInfo", privateGetterFlags);
            var m_errorInfo = field.GetValue(m_currentResult);
            field = m_errorInfo.GetType().GetField("m_stackTrace", privateGetterFlags);
            m_message = field.GetValue(m_errorInfo) as string;
        }

        return m_message;
    }
```

To get the error message it is similar:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns Error Message Details extracted from TestContext
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="testContext"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetErrorMessageFromTestContext(TestContext testContext)
    {
        const BindingFlags privateGetterFlags = System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField |
                                                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty |
                                                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy;

        var m_message = string.Empty; // Returns empty if TestOutcome is not failed
        if (testContext.CurrentTestOutcome == UnitTestOutcome.Failed)
        {
            // Get hold of TestContext.m_currentResult.m_errorInfo.m_message (contains the exception text that was thrown)
            var field = testContext.GetType().GetField("m_currentResult", privateGetterFlags);
            var m_currentResult = field.GetValue(testContext);
            field = m_currentResult.GetType().GetField("m_errorInfo", privateGetterFlags);
            var m_errorInfo = field.GetValue(m_currentResult);
            field = m_errorInfo.GetType().GetField("m_message", privateGetterFlags);
            m_message = field.GetValue(m_errorInfo) as string;
        }

        return m_message;
    }
```

Comment: OMG. You saved my life :) - I've been looking for this answer for a long time. Finally I can grab the error!